# Determine the positions of the points on the surface of a cylinder at which the pressure is minimum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, potential-flow

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem, as I'm unsure on how to begin.  The problem is the following.

Two equal line sources of strength $k$ are located at $x=3a$ and $x=-3a$, near a circular cylinder of radius $a$ with axis normal to the $x-y$ plane and passing through the origin. The fluid is incompressible and the flow is irrotational and inviscid. I have used  the Milne-Thomson circle theorem to show that the complex potential for this flow is 
$$ w(z) = k\ln\left(a^{4}-9a^{2}z^{2}-9\frac{a^{6}}{z^{2}}+81a^{4}\right). $$

I also know that the speed of the flow at the surface of the cylinder  is given by $$|\frac{dw}{dz}|,$$  from the previous part of the question  that i'm doing i know that this is given by $$|\frac{dw}{dz}|=v=\frac{18k\sin(2\theta)}{a(41-9\cos(2\theta))}$$

My main problem is how would i Determine the positions of the points on the surface of the cylinder at which the pressure is minimum, intuition would indicate that the pressure would be lower at the top of the cylinder, however i'm unsure of this.